# I tried to install Fedora over Windows, but when I try to boot the Windows Recovery appears

Tags: linux, windows, boot, fedora

I tried to install Fedora using the Live USB, thinking that it would overwrite windows, but now when I try to boot it says 'Windows recovery'.
I had deleted all partitions during the installation.
A friend suggested using 'dd' to wipe out the boot loader, is there anything else I could do instead?

Comment: Are you booting with UEFI or BIOS?